# Does the second boolean after && executes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm still new to rails and lots of it is not what I'm used to. Couldn’t find my answer on this and don’t actually know what to search for so please help.

Is this:

```
def create
    @note = Note.new(params[:note])
    @note.creator = current_user
    if member_of_project? @note.project_id
      if @note.save
        redirect_to @note, :notice => "Successfully created note."
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Equal to:

```
def create
    @note = Note.new(params[:note])
    @note.creator = current_user
    if member_of_project? @note.project_id && @note.save
      redirect_to @note, :notice => "Successfully created note."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

???

What I really want to know is if the second one will call `@note.save`.

Comment: I suspect this more of a 'ruby' question than a 'rails' question.  You may want to investigate if this behavior is consistent through whichever version of ruby you choose to run with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby, like a lot of other languages will implement "short-circuit evaluation" which means that the second operand only gets evaluated in an "and" if the first operand is true. You can read more here for ruby specifics: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Ruby_Expressions_Defined_And_Or_and_Not.html

Comment: Thanks. This will be read multiply times so its really get stucked in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have tried it and it failed. Yes, if it gets to the second part of the conditional, the save method should run.

I have found that in the event of using a conditional like this, I need to wrap it in parenthesis to get the code to run properly.

```
 if (member_of_project? @note.project_id) && (@note.save)
```

And of course what kind of developer would I be if I didn't ask 'What do your tests tell you?'

Comment: Yes the reason I asked was because it did execute @note.save even if the member_of_project? should be false. It turned out that my helper was not working as it should.